# Apply custom (ANOVA-like) contrasts to all interactions in a mixed model (with a stacked dataset)

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, mediation, contrasts

I am conducting a multilevel mediation analysis with a multicategorical X (4 levels from a 2-by-2 design) for which I want to apply `custom contrasts` that code two main effects and an interaction. For a stacked dataset with two indicator variables (Sm and Sy), a numerical outcome (Y) and mediator (M), I have following "issue" when calling a lmer:

The `model.matrix` below shows that the contrast for X is only applied to one interaction term (Sy:X) and not for the remaining interaction (Sm:X). Accordingly, the model coefficients reflect this contrast for the Sy:X-interaction, but for the Sm:X they show the comparison with the reference level.

```
    Sm Sy Sm:X1 Sm:X2 Sm:X3 Sy:X1 Sy:X2 Sy:X3      Sy:M
1    0  1     0     0     0    -1    -1     1 1.5902378
2    0  1     0     0     0    -1     1    -1 0.8355516
3    0  1     0     0     0     1    -1    -1 0.7563719
4    0  1     0     0     0     1     1     1 0.3320396
5    0  1     0     0     0    -1    -1     1 1.4224360
....
121  1  0     1     0     0     0     0     0 0.000000
122  1  0     0     1     0     0     0     0 0.000000
123  1  0     0     0     1     0     0     0 0.000000
124  1  0     0     0     0     0     0     0 0.000000
125  1  0     1     0     0     0     0     0 0.000000
126  1  0     0     1     0     0     0     0 0.000000
127  1  0     0     0     1     0     0     0 0.000000
```

However, my idea was to apply the custom contrast for `X` to all interactions in which the variable `X` is involved. Where am I missing something?

Below should be a reproducible example:

Example DF with `X` (predictor; categorical), `M` (mediator; numerical), `Y` (outcome; numerical), `ID` (grouping variable; factors):

```
library(lme4)
library(reshape2)
# Number of subjects
n_subjects <- 30

# Number of conditions
n_conditions <- 4

# Levels of conditions
conditions <- factor(rep(1:n_conditions, times = n_subjects))

# Generate random data for mediator variable M with subject and condition effects
M <- rnorm(n_subjects * n_conditions, mean = rep(1:n_conditions, each = n_subjects), sd = 0.5)

# Generate random data for outcome variable Y with subject and condition effects
Y <- rnorm(n_subjects * n_conditions, mean = rep(1:n_conditions, each = n_subjects), sd = 1)

# Create a data frame
DF <- data.frame(ID = rep(1:n_subjects, each = n_conditions),
                   X = as.factor(conditions),
                   M = M,
                   Y = Y)
```

Create custom contrast and apply to X:

```
 custom_contrasts <- matrix(c(-1, -1, 1, 
                                   -1, 1, -1,
                                   1, -1, -1,  
                                   1, 1, 1),   
                                 nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)
contrasts(DF$X) <- custom_contrasts
```

Now stack the dataset:

```
DF$fid <- 1:nrow(DF)
stacked <- melt(DF, id.vars = c("fid", "ID", "Y", "X","M"),
                measure.vars = c("Y", "M"), value.name = "Z")
stacked <- within(stacked, {
  Sy <- as.integer(variable == "Y")
  Sm <- as.integer(variable == "M")
})
```

The reason for stacking the dataset is to re-formulate the two formulas...
`model.m = lme4::lmer(M ~ 1 + X + (1 | ID) , data = DF)`
`model.y = lme4::lmer(Y ~ 1 + X + M + (1|ID), data = DF)`

...into one formula with a new response variable `Z` with `Y` stacked on `M` and estimate the model*:
`mm = lme4::lmer(Z ~ 0 + Sm + Sy + Sm:X+ Sy:X+ Sy:M+ (0 + Sm + Sy | ID) , data = stacked)`

- `Sm`: The intercept for M
- `Sy`: The intercept for Y // `Sm` and `Sy` are indicator variables.
- `SmX`: Regression coefficient for X->M (a path)
- `SyM`: Regression coefficient for M->Y (b path)
- `SyX`: Regression coefficient for X->Y (cprime path)

see: [multilevel mediation example](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-can-i-perform-mediation-with-multilevel-data-method-2/) for another example of how and why to stack the dataset (in this case X is numerical, so no contrast needed)

Now, when inspecting the `model.matrix` the contrast is correctly coded for Sy:X1 to Sy:X3. For Sm:X1 to Sm:X3 the contrast is still a treatment (?) contrast:

```
# Inspect the model matrix
m.matrix = getME(mm, "X")
View(m.matrix)
```

Thanks:)

Comment: The following "issue" did not go through not in your post.

Comment: I tried to restructure my post/question to make sure the issue I am having is a bit clearer. To summarize: The contrast I am previously assigning to 'X' is not applied to all interactions where 'X' is involved.